# How to add helm repo from an existing github project?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an existing github project. I want to create/add a `helm` folder to the project to store the helm yaml files. I want to reference this github project/folder to act like a helm repo in my local/dev environment. I know I can add the charts to my local/default helm repo. The use case is if another developer checks out the code in github and he needs to work on the charts then he can run `helm install` directly from the working folder. The `helm.sh` website has instructions of adding a `gh-pages` branch but I am wondering if I can avoid it.

Can I use an existing github project and it via the `helm repo add` command?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a way to publish helm charts via GitHub using private repositories. On a theoretical level, it might work using GitHub token and 2nd (raw URLs method), but I haven't tried it. Since you're using docker registry anyway, it might be worth trying using OCI (docker) registry to store the charts.

If that doesn't work, or you have public repos, it is possible to either use GitHub Pages, or use GitHub raw URLs. Both of the solutions require public repository.

To use **GitHub pages**:

- Setup github pages to publish `docs` folder as github pages (you can use a different name, just substitue later)
- Package the helm repo as .tgz (using `helm package`): `helm package charts/mychart -d docs/`. Substitute `charts/mychart` with a path to a chart root folder
- Include an index.yaml -- an index file for the repository `helm repo index ./docs --url https://<YOUR_ORG_OR_USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO_NAME>`

Now you can add the repo: `helm repo add <INTERNAL_NAME> https://<YOUR_ORG_OR_USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO_NAME>`

To use **Raw URLs**:

- Place index.yaml and chart TGZs into a folder called `docs`, just like above

Now you can add a repo: `helm repo add <INTERNAL_NAME> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<YOUR_ORG_OR_USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>/<BRANCH_USUALLY_MASTER>/docs`

Comment: Publishing is working fine. When I try to install the chart, `Error: file '/Users/a212750606/Library/Caches/helm/repository/name-1.0.0.tgz' does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'`.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly make sure that you have have fully functional helm repository. The tricky part is to access it as if it was simple HTTP server hosting raw files. Fortunately Github provides such feature using `raw.githubusercontent.com`. In order for helm to be able to pull files from such repository you need to provide it with Github username and token (Personal Access Token):

```
> helm repo add - username <your_github_username> - password <your_github_token> my-github-helm-repo 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my_organization/my-github-helm-repo/master/'
> helm repo update
> helm repo list
NAME URL
stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
local http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
my-github-helmrepo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my_organization/my-github-helm-repo/master/
> helm search my-app
NAME CHART VERSION APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
my-github-helmrepo/my-app-chart 0.1.0 1.0 A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

**These are steps for adding new packages to existing repository**

If you want to add new package to existing repository simply:

**1.** Place new package in your local repository root

**2.** Execute: helm repo index .. This will detect new file/folder and make updates.

**3.** Commit and push your new package

**4.** Finally execute command: `helm repo update`

**Security ascpect**

It is important to realize where does helm actually store your [Github token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line). It is stored as plain text in `~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml`. In this case it will be good to generate token with as few permissions as possible.

Take a look here: [hosting helm private repository](https://blog.softwaremill.com/hosting-helm-private-repository-from-github-ff3fa940d0b7).

Comment: Publishing is working fine. When I try to install the chart, `Error: file '/Users/a212750606/Library/Caches/helm/repository/name-1.0.0.tgz' does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'`.