# Use git as helm repo throws "does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'"

Tags: github, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm exploring various options to publish charts and referred [How to add helm repo from an existing github project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59704891/how-to-add-helm-repo-from-an-existing-github-project) to achieve it. But when I tried to install the chart, I got the error `Error: file '/Users/my_home/Library/Caches/helm/repository/chart-1.0.0.tgz' does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'`

Tried [chart-releaser](https://github.com/helm/chart-releaser) to publish the chart to git. In this case also getting the same error.

When I tried to do `wget https://github.com/repo/charts/releases/download/app-1.0.0/chart-1.0.0.tgz` content-type is `text/html`. What's going wrong in this case? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, GitHub is private repo and authentication is required to pull the charts.

What I was doing?

```
helm repo index CHART_NAME --url <Full URL to chart.tgz file>
```

But

```
helm repo add --username u_name --password token <name> https://github.com/raw/ORG/charts/master
```

will add the helm repo, but `helm install <name>` won't use the same git token passed in previous step.

How to fix it?

```
helm package <CHART_NAME> -u -d .deploy
helm repo index .
```

In this case, index.yaml will contain the relative URL to chart not absolute url.

Same auth tokens are used to fetch `.tgz` file as well while running `helm install`

Comment: This was the key for me. I also was doing this on a private repo, and the `-u` and `-d` flags fixed it for me immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is still a problem on helm 3.2.0 but fixed in 3.2.4. Helm charts with ".tgz" fail, but charts with some random extension like ".gzip" download successfully with helm. So install helm v3.2.4.
Here you can find information how to install helm 3.2.4 - [helm-3.2.4](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.2.4).

Please take a look: [helm-chart-issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2916#issuecomment-678930024), [helm-gzip](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2916#issuecomment-617060227).

Comment: Updated to the latest version of helm i.e `3.3.4` and I still see the same problem.
Is there any way to package with some other extension like `.tar` or `.tar.gz`

Comment: My bad. Even though I made the repo as public, my company github page needs to login before accessing any page. I passed auth to helm like `helm repo add test --username my_name --password some_token https://git.mycompany.com/my_name/charts`. But same auth is not used to pull the chart. Listing the charts works by running command `helm repo search chartname`

Comment: Please add above information to your post, also downgrade of the helm should work properly.

Comment: Found the fix. Authentication isn't working if I mention the complete URL to `.tar.gz`. If its relative url, authentication is working.

Comment: Can you post it as an alternative solution - for community ?

Comment: same bug on 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the **.tgz** file is downloadable.

**For example:**

This looks like a **valid** chart URL but **not** and when you try to download by clicking the URL. You will see this is **not downloadable**.

```
https://github.com/pantsel/konga/blob/master/charts/konga/konga-1.0.0.tgz
```

So, you need a **downloadable version** of the URL like the following;

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pantsel/konga/master/charts/konga/konga-1.0.0.tgz
```

Hope this will work for you.