# Convert Github HELM chart into standard Kubernetes manifests?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, manifest

There is this HELM chart (https://github.com/cdwv/bitwarden-k8s) that I would like to convert to standard Kubernetes manifests.

When trying to use `helm template` I get *does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'application/octet-stream'*

Any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are enjoying your Kubernetes journey !

First question, is your helm chart gziped/tarballed and Have you been able to download your chart and you unzip/untar it? Is it a private github repo?

You can check this post for maybe solving your pb: [Use git as helm repo throws "does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320225/use-git-as-helm-repo-throws-does-not-appear-to-be-a-gzipped-archive-got-text)

Which command do you use to templatize your helm chart?
I mean, when you have downloaded and unzipped your chart, you can just cd in the directory where there is the values and templates and type:

```
helm template <randomName> .
```

and you'll get your k8s files completed with the values.

Waiting for your answer.
bguess.

Comment: So the repo is public and I'm able to download it and untar it. When I'm in the directory with values.yaml and template folder and do `helm template <randomName>` I get error saying `Error: failed to download <name I gave>`

Comment: Update - Got it! I needed to specify the chart folder. Thank you!

Comment: Oh great haha (this "." is sometimes unseeable), Happy for you ! You are welcome, Bye